# java ftp zip better way

Tags: java, ftp

I have seen using java.util.zip.ZipEntry we can zip file.

I am able to zip it and also I am transferring it from one **FTP** location and to other FTP location

```
 outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry());
 while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) 
 {      
     outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
     ByteWritten += ByteRead;
 }
```

I also seen there there is some method FTP.sendCommand() .
but not sure how I can use it to send command to zip a file in one FTP location and copy to another lcoation using this method.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: The FTP.sendCommand() is for FTP commands, in order to ZIP a remote file, I would say you need to use SSH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [zip the files which are present at one FTP location and copy to another FTP location directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933180/zip-the-files-which-are-present-at-one-ftp-location-and-copy-to-another-ftp-loca)

Answer (score 1):

I think you achieve it in two steps:

1. Zip the file and write in first FTP location

   ```
   URL ftpLocation1 = new URL("ftp://url1");
   URLConnection ftpConnect1 = ftpLocation1.openConnection();
   OutputStream ftpOutStream1 = ftpConnect1.getOutputStream(); // To upload
   ftpOutStream1.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry());
   while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {      
      ftpOutStream1.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
      ByteWritten += ByteRead;
    }
   ```
2. read the zip file as it is and write to second FTP location

   ```
   InputStream ftpInputStream1 = ftpConnect1.getInputStream(); // To read back
   URL ftpLocation2 = new URL("ftp://url2");
   URLConnection ftpConnect2 = ftpLocation1.openConnection();
   OutputStream ftpOutStream2 = ftpConnect2.getOutputStream(); // To upload

   //read through ftpInputStream1 and write in ftpOutStream2 
   while ((ByteRead = ftpInputStream1.read(buf)) != -1) {      
      ftpOutStream2.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
      ByteWritten += ByteRead;
    }
   ```
3. Once done, close all the streams