# zip the files which are present at one FTP location and copy to another FTP location directly

Tags: java, ftp, zip

I want to **create zip file of files which are present at one ftp location and Copy this zip file to other ftp location without saving locally.**

I am able to handle this for small size of files.It works well for small size files 1 mb etc

But if file size is big like 100 MB, 200 MB , 300 MB then its giving error as,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: STOR myfile.zip : 550 The process cannot access the 
file because it is being used by another process. 
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.readReply(FtpClient.java:251)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.issueCommand(FtpClient.java:208)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openDataConnection(FtpClient.java:398) 
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.put(FtpClient.java:609)
```

My code is

```
    URLConnection  urlConnection=null;
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream=null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    byte[] buf;
    int ByteRead,ByteWritten=0; 
    ***Destination where file will be zipped***
    URL url = new URL("ftp://" + ftpuser+ ":" + ftppass + "@"+ ftppass + "/" +
            fileNameToStore + ";type=i");
    urlConnection=url.openConnection();         
    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    buf = new byte[size];
    for (int i=0; i<li.size(); i++) 
    {
        try
        {
            ***Souce from where file will be read***
            URL u= new URL((String)li.get(i));  // this li has values http://xyz.com/folder
            /myPDF.pdf
            URLConnection uCon = u.openConnection();
            inputStream = uCon.getInputStream();
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry((String)li.get(i).substring((int)li.get(i).lastIndexOf("/")+1).trim()));
            while ((ByteRead = inputStream .read(buf)) != -1)    
            {       
                zipOutputStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
                ByteWritten += ByteRead;
            }
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (inputStream  != null) {
        try { 
            inputStream .close(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (zipOutputStream != null) {
        try { 
            zipOutputStream.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }     
    }
```

Can anybody let me know how I can avoid this error and handle large files

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to file sizes; as the error says, you can't replace the file because some other process is currently locking it.

The reason why you see it more often with large files is because these take longer to transfer hence the chance of concurrent accesses is higher.

So the only solution is to make sure that no one uses the file when you try to transfer it. Good luck with that.

Possible other solutions:

1. Don't use Windows on the server.
2. Transfer the file under a temporary name and rename it when it's complete. That way, other processes won't see incomplete files. Always a good thing.
3. Use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead of inventing the wheel again.

Comment: Hello @Aaron. if you can provide me more information on point no 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Feel free to post new questions. Just make sure you specifically mention what you need to know/don't understand.

Comment: @Aaron.Thanks.for point 2. initially I am creating destination zip file name and then iterating over my list(files which I will be adding to zip) and adding it in above destination zip. I don't understand this renaming thing which you suggested.How I can achieve this. Also i totally not understood your point no 3.

Comment: Renaming doesn't work when you use `URLConnection`. Use the [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) from [commons net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) instead. `rsync` is a tool. I added a link to the docs in my answer above.

Comment: can you please tell me how I can use FTPClient from commons net.Since I want to store my zipped file from one FTP location to another FTP location directly and storeFile method of FTPClient accept inputstream while storing.

Comment: hello @Aaron. Is there a way I can delete my zip file using URLConnection. since I am creating first zip file as ,URL url = new URL("ftp://"+ftpuser+":"+ftppass+"@"+ ftppass+"/"+ZipfileNameToStore+";type=i"); then I am adding inputstram to this. But if there is any exception I want to delete this file. I didnt see any way using URLconnection. Although FTPClient has deleteFile() method I am not sure my entire functionality will work with FTPClient ie directly reading,zipping from one ftp put to another FTP.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `FTPClient` and play with it. If you have any specific questions, ask a new question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, before we had network security, there were FTP servers that allowed 3rd party transfers. You could use site specific commands and send a file to another FTP server directly. Those days are long gone. Sigh.

Ok, maybe not long gone. Some FTP servers support the *proxy* command. There is a discussion here: http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/resources/manuals/Unix_Unleashed/Vol_1/ch27.htm